# Is it possible to store the translation table in localstorage with angular-translate for an offline use of my app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate, ng-storage

I'm developing a multi-language app with Ionic and angular-translate. I get the translation table from a server with `$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader`.
It works like a charm as long as the app has an internet connection.

The problem is that the client could use the app offline and of course, when you launch the app without internet, it breaks cause translations are not available.

Does anyone knows if it's possible to store the translation table in localstorage (or whatever) and tell angular-translate to use the local translations in order to prevent the app from breaking when there's no internet?

Thank you for your help.